# Want to return a promise based on a series of other promise completioen

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, q

Heres my code:

```
var delete_card = function(){

  stripe.customers.deleteCard(
    this.service_id.stripe,
    this.credit_card[0].stripe_id
  )
  .then(function(obj){
    this.recipients.splice(0, 1);
    return this.save()
  })
}
```

Both the stripe call and the  save call return promises.

How would I RETURN a promise from the delete_card method?

Would I wrap them all in like new Promise and return a promise from there?
How would I structure that so I bubble up both errors and results?

I want to be able to do something from the caller like this:

```
delete_card
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

And just keep  composing chained promises?

Comment: "*Would I wrap them all in like new Promise and return a promise from there?*" - [**NOOO!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)

Comment: Hahahaha I read some best practices that  said that was a bad idea.  zero's answer below was exactly what I was looking for and it makes sense too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return the promise in the `delete_card` function.

```
var delete_card = function(){

  /************/
  /**/return/**/ stripe.customers.deleteCard(
  /************/
    this.service_id.stripe,
    this.credit_card[0].stripe_id
  )
  .then(function(obj){
    this.recipients.splice(0, 1);
    return this.save()
  })
}
```

---

**Edit:** I made it obnoxiously obvious where to add the `return` since the code difference is so subtle.

Comment: YES. Thank you. I kept trying to  retur the  `this.save()` and getting an undefined `then` error.

Then I noticed you were returning the entire chain at the top: `return stripe....` 

It works! Thank you!

Promises are so nice, I cant even look at a callback again.

Comment: @NickKiermaier Ha, I made it a bit more obvious where the difference is in case someone else comes and can't tell what I changed.  Sorry about that.